# ToC Indent and Memoir Class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, indentation

I am using Memoir class to my PhD Thesis and I need to move the List of Figures and List of Tables indentation to be aligned to Acknowledgements and Abstract.

```
\documentclass[
% -- opções da classe memoir --
12pt,                   % Tamanho da fonte
openright,          % Capítulos começam em página ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
oneside,             % Para impressão em frente e verso. Opções oneside ou twoside.
a4paper,            % Tamanho do papel
sumario=tradicional, % Atleração do template do sumário 
% -- opções da classe abntex2 --
%chapter=TITLE,       % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%section=TITLE,        % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas 
% -- opções do pacote babel --
french,         % Idioma adicional para hifenização
spanish,       % Idioma adicional para hifenização
brazil,           % Idioma adicional para hifenização
english        % O último idioma é o principal do documento
]{abntex2}       
    
% Pacotes básicos 
% ---
\usepackage{helvet}                  % Usa a fonte Arial    
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}       

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % Seleção de códigos de fonte
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{indentfirst}         % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção
\usepackage{color}                 % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}            % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{microtype}         % Para melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{tocloft}               % Fornece meios de controlar o design tipográfico do Índice, Lista de Figuras e Lista de Tabelas
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   % Pacote para gerenciar cores no documento
\usepackage{hyperref}            % Usado para lidar com comandos de referência cruzada e para produzir links de hipetexto no documento
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % Oferece comandos para a construção de cabeçalhos e rodapés
\usepackage{lastpage}            % Obtém o número da última página do documento - usado por abntex2-fichacatalografica.tex
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float} % Força o posicionamento de figuras
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell, cellspace, caption}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript} % Atalho para sobrescrito
\newcommand{\tsb}{\textsubscript} % Atalho para subscrito

\usepackage{lipsum}
% ---
% Pacotes de citações
    
\usepackage[alf,abnt-etal-cite=3,abnt-etal-list=0]{abntex2cite} % Citações padrão ABNT
    
% ---
% Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
% ---
\title{Routine microseismic monitoring in mine: Natural seismic events and blast-induced seismicity in tailings dam - Case study of Cajati/SP}
\newcommand{\titulopt}{Monitoramento microssísmico de rotina em minas: Eventos sísmicos naturais e sismicidade induzida por desmontes em barragem de rejeitos - Estudo de caso de Cajati/SP}
\author{Leonardo Santana de Oliveira Dias}
\newcommand{\authorfc}{DIAS, Leonardo Santana de Oliveira} % Para colocar na primeira página da ficha catalográfica
\local{Rio de Janeiro}
\date{2021}
\instituicao{UFRJ / Igeo}
\newcommand{\instituicaofull}{Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro, Instituto de Geociências, Programa de Pós-graduação em Geologia}
\newcommand{\instituicaoabs}{Programa de Pós-graduação em Geologia, Instituto de Geociências, Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro}
\newcommand{\instituicaoabsen}{Graduate Program in Geology, Geosciences Institute, Federal University of Rio de Janeiro}
\orientador{Marco Antonio Braga}
% \coorientador{A DEFINIR}  % Permite a inserção de coorientador
\tipotrabalho{Tese de Doutorado (Geologia)\\Ph.D. Thesis (Geology)}
\newcommand{\tipotrabalhofc}{Tese (Doutorado em Geologia)}
\newcommand{\tipotrabalhofcen}{Thesis (PhD in Geology)}
\preambulo{A thesis submitted to the Graduate Program in Geology, Institute of Geosciences, Federal University of Rio de Janeiro (UFRJ) in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Doctor of Science (Geology).\vspace*{0.2cm} \\
Concentration Area: Geophysics\vspace*{0.2cm} \\
Sector: Engineering and Environmental Geology\vspace*{0.2cm} \\
Advisor: Marco Antonio Braga, Ph.D - UFRJ}
% ---
    
% CUSTOMIZAÇÃO DA CAPA E FOLHA DE ROSTO
\usepackage{ufrj-abntex2}   % Usa o arquivo - ufrj-abntex2.sty
    
% ---
% Configurações de aparência do PDF final
    
% alterando o aspecto da cor azul
\definecolor{black}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    
% informações do PDF
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    %pagebackref=true,
    pdftitle={\@title}, 
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
    pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
    pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{trabalho acadêmico}, 
    colorlinks=true,            % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,             % color of internal links
    citecolor=black,                % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,       % color of file links
    urlcolor=black,
    bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother
% --- 
    
% ---
% Posiciona figuras e tabelas no topo da página quando adicionadas sozinhas
% em um página em branco. Ver https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/issues/170
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt} % Set distance from top of page to first float
\makeatother
% ---
    
% ---
% COLOCAR O TAMANHO DOS TÍTULOS DOS CAPÍTULOS NO TAMANO 12PT E EM NEGRITO
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfontsize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfontsize}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\bfseries}    
% ---

% ---
% Compila o índice
% ---
\makeindex
% ---
    
% --- Corrigir hifenização das palavras nas quebras de parágrafos
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
% ---
    
%-- Altera o título do TOC
    
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {TABLE OF CONTENTS}%
}
    
\nobibintoc %Esconde o título padrão da bilbliografia do TOC
        
%%% -----
%%% Formato de cabeçalho/rodapé romano nos elementos pré-textuais
%%% -----
    
%% Novo estilo
\makepagestyle{estilo_pretextual} %%% escolha um nome
\makeevenhead{estilo_pretextual}{}{}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida \textbf \thepage}
\makeoddhead{estilo_pretextual}{}{}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida \textbf \thepage}
    
%% Customiza comando \pretextual
\renewcommand{\pretextual}{
    \pagenumbering{roman} %%% ou \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \aliaspagestyle{chapter}{estilo_pretextual}% customizing chapter pagestyle
    \pagestyle{estilo_pretextual}
    \aliaspagestyle{cleared}{empty}
    \aliaspagestyle{part}{estilo_pretextual}
}
    
% ---
% Ajusta a marca \textual para que a numeração volte a ser arábica
% nos elementos textuais
\let\oldtextual\textual        % copia o comando \textual anterior para \oldtextual
\renewcommand{\textual}{%
    \oldtextual%
    \pagenumbering{arabic} % volta à numeração arábica
}


% ---
        
% ----------------------------
% INÍCIO DO DOCUMENTO
% ----------------------------
    
\begin{document}
        
% Altera o padrão ABNTEX para inglês
%\selectlanguage{english}
    
% Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
\frenchspacing 
    
\imprimircapa
    
\setcounter{page}{2} % Faz com que que contagem inclua a capa   
    
\imprimirfolhaderosto
        
\input{chapters/ficha_catalografica}
    
\input{chapters/folha_de_aprovacao}
    
\input{chapters/dedicatoria}
    
\input{chapters/agradecimentos}
    
\input{chapters/epigrafe}
    
\input{chapters/resumos}
    
% Cria a TABLE OF CONTENTS
%   \begingroup
%   \pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}     
%   \tableofcontents*
%   \cleardoublepage
%   \endgroup
%---

% Lista de figuras
%   \pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
%   \listoffigures*
%   \cleardoublepage
%---

% Lista de tabelas
%   \pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
%   \listoftables*
%   \cleardoublepage
%---

\tableofcontents*   
\cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}} % Coloca a página em Romano sem reinicar a contagem  

% CAPÍTULOS DA TESE
\input{chapters/1-introduction}

\input{chapters/2-geology and structures}

\input{chapters/3-tailings dams and geotechnics}

\input{chapters/4-microseismic}

\input{chapters/5-paper1}

\input{chapters/6-paper2}

\input{chapters/7-discussions}

\input{chapters/8-conclusions}

%   \input{chapters/9-schedule and next steps}
    
% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Referências bibliográficas
% ----------------------------------------------------------
    
\chapter{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf}
\bibliography{references}
\endgroup
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You are using class `abntex2` and not `memoir`. Please clarify ...

Comment: @Mensch abntex variants are build on top of memoir.

Comment: Please make your example compilable for others by making sure it is not using anything others do not have access to. For example we do not have access to the files you input.

Comment: Additionally tocloft does nothing with anything me our related and could be removed. Please make sure your example is minimal and only use stuff related to your problem

Comment: In the default `memoir` the ToC entries for Abstract etc, and List of would be aligned with the 1 of Introduction. It's porbable that you have a problem with using `abntex2`. I don't understand Spanish, or is it Portugese?

Comment: I can not find `ufrj-abntex2`. Do you have a link to it?

Answer (score 1):

Add this two lines before `\begin{document}`

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\hspace*{-1.5em}} 
\cftsetindents{chapter}{1.5em}{0em}
```

[image: A]

Complete code (without using `\usepackage{ufrj-abntex2}`, not  founded, but this only affects the cover)

```
\documentclass[
% -- opções da classe memoir --
12pt,                   % Tamanho da fonte
openright,          % Capítulos começam em página ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
oneside,             % Para impressão em frente e verso. Opções oneside ou twoside.
a4paper,            % Tamanho do papel
sumario=tradicional, % Atleração do template do sumário 
% -- opções da classe abntex2 --
%chapter=TITLE,       % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%section=TITLE,        % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas 
% -- opções do pacote babel --
french,         % Idioma adicional para hifenização
spanish,       % Idioma adicional para hifenização
brazil,           % Idioma adicional para hifenização
english        % O último idioma é o principal do documento
]{abntex2}       

% Pacotes básicos 
% ---
\usepackage{helvet}                  % Usa a fonte Arial    
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}       

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % Seleção de códigos de fonte
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{indentfirst}         % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção
\usepackage{color}                 % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}            % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{microtype}         % Para melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{tocloft}               % Fornece meios de controlar o design tipográfico do Índice, Lista de Figuras e Lista de Tabelas
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   % Pacote para gerenciar cores no documento
\usepackage{hyperref}            % Usado para lidar com comandos de referência cruzada e para produzir links de hipetexto no documento
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % Oferece comandos para a construção de cabeçalhos e rodapés
\usepackage{lastpage}            % Obtém o número da última página do documento - usado por abntex2-fichacatalografica.tex
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float} % Força o posicionamento de figuras
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell, cellspace, caption}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript} % Atalho para sobrescrito
\newcommand{\tsb}{\textsubscript} % Atalho para subscrito

\usepackage{lipsum}
% ---
% Pacotes de citações

\usepackage[alf,abnt-etal-cite=3,abnt-etal-list=0]{abntex2cite} % Citações padrão ABNT

% ---
% Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
% ---
\title{Routine microseismic monitoring in mine: Natural seismic events and blast-induced seismicity in tailings dam - Case study of Cajati/SP}
\newcommand{\titulopt}{Monitoramento microssísmico de rotina em minas: Eventos sísmicos naturais e sismicidade induzida por desmontes em barragem de rejeitos - Estudo de caso de Cajati/SP}
\author{Leonardo Santana de Oliveira Dias}
\newcommand{\authorfc}{DIAS, Leonardo Santana de Oliveira} % Para colocar na primeira página da ficha catalográfica
\local{Rio de Janeiro}
\date{2021}
\instituicao{UFRJ / Igeo}
\newcommand{\instituicaofull}{Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro, Instituto de Geociências, Programa de Pós-graduação em Geologia}
\newcommand{\instituicaoabs}{Programa de Pós-graduação em Geologia, Instituto de Geociências, Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro}
\newcommand{\instituicaoabsen}{Graduate Program in Geology, Geosciences Institute, Federal University of Rio de Janeiro}
\orientador{Marco Antonio Braga}
% \coorientador{A DEFINIR}  % Permite a inserção de coorientador
\tipotrabalho{Tese de Doutorado (Geologia)\\Ph.D. Thesis (Geology)}
\newcommand{\tipotrabalhofc}{Tese (Doutorado em Geologia)}
\newcommand{\tipotrabalhofcen}{Thesis (PhD in Geology)}
\preambulo{A thesis submitted to the Graduate Program in Geology, Institute of Geosciences, Federal University of Rio de Janeiro (UFRJ) in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Doctor of Science (Geology).\vspace*{0.2cm} \\
    Concentration Area: Geophysics\vspace*{0.2cm} \\
    Sector: Engineering and Environmental Geology\vspace*{0.2cm} \\
    Advisor: Marco Antonio Braga, Ph.D - UFRJ}
% ---

% CUSTOMIZAÇÃO DA CAPA E FOLHA DE ROSTO
%%\usepackage{ufrj-abntex2}   % Usa o arquivo - ufrj-abntex2.sty  NOT FOUND <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% ---
% Configurações de aparência do PDF final

% alterando o aspecto da cor azul
\definecolor{black}{RGB}{0,0,0}

% informações do PDF
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    %pagebackref=true,
    pdftitle={\@title}, 
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
    pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
    pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{trabalho acadêmico}, 
    colorlinks=true,            % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,             % color of internal links
    citecolor=black,                % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,       % color of file links
    urlcolor=black,
    bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother
% --- 

% ---
% Posiciona figuras e tabelas no topo da página quando adicionadas sozinhas
% em um página em branco. Ver https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/issues/170
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt} % Set distance from top of page to first float
\makeatother
% ---

% ---
% COLOCAR O TAMANHO DOS TÍTULOS DOS CAPÍTULOS NO TAMANO 12PT E EM NEGRITO
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfontsize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfontsize}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\bfseries}    
% ---

% ---
% Compila o índice
% ---
\makeindex
% ---

% --- Corrigir hifenização das palavras nas quebras de parágrafos
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
% ---

%-- Altera o título do TOC

\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {TABLE OF CONTENTS}%
}

\nobibintoc %Esconde o título padrão da bilbliografia do TOC

%%% -----
%%% Formato de cabeçalho/rodapé romano nos elementos pré-textuais
%%% -----

%% Novo estilo
\makepagestyle{estilo_pretextual} %%% escolha um nome
\makeevenhead{estilo_pretextual}{}{}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida \textbf \thepage}
\makeoddhead{estilo_pretextual}{}{}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida \textbf \thepage}

%% Customiza comando \pretextual
\renewcommand{\pretextual}{
    \pagenumbering{roman} %%% ou \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \aliaspagestyle{chapter}{estilo_pretextual}% customizing chapter pagestyle
    \pagestyle{estilo_pretextual}
    \aliaspagestyle{cleared}{empty}
    \aliaspagestyle{part}{estilo_pretextual}
}

% ---
% Ajusta a marca \textual para que a numeração volte a ser arábica
% nos elementos textuais
\let\oldtextual\textual        % copia o comando \textual anterior para \oldtextual
\renewcommand{\textual}{%
    \oldtextual%
    \pagenumbering{arabic} % volta à numeração arábica
}

% ----------------------------
% INÍCIO DO DOCUMENTO
% ----------------------------



\renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\hspace*{-1.5em}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\cftsetindents{chapter}{1.5em}{0em} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    % Altera o padrão ABNTEX para inglês
    %\selectlanguage{english}
    
    % Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
    \frenchspacing 
    \frontmatter %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        
    \imprimircapa
    
    \setcounter{page}{2} % Faz com que que contagem inclua a capa   
    
    \imprimirfolhaderosto
    

    \chapter*{Ficha-catalografica}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ficha-catalografica}     
    
    \chapter*{Folha-de-aprovacao}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Folha-de-aprovacao}  
    
    \chapter*{Dedicatoria}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedicatoria}     
    
    \chapter*{Agradecimentos}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Agradecimentos}
    
    \chapter*{Epigrafe}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Epigrafe}
            
    \cleardoublepage
    \tableofcontents*   
    \cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures
    \cleardoublepage
    \listoftables
    \cleardoublepage
    
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}} % Coloca a página em Romano sem reinicar a contagem  
    
    % CAPÍTULOS DA TESE

    \mainmatter % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
     \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \chapter{Geology and structures}
    
    \chapter{Tailings dams and geotechnics}
    
    \chapter{Microseismic}
    
    \chapter{Paper1}
    
    \chapter{Paper2}
    
    \chapter{Discussions}
    
    \chapter{Conclusions}
    
    % ----------------------------------------------------------
    % Referências bibliográficas
    % ----------------------------------------------------------
    
    \chapter{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    
\end{document}
```